# Accessing UserData on objects resulting from Raycast Intersection

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I'm trying to display the name of a hovered object in a WebGL scene powered by three.js. I'm raycasting with the `Raycaster` class and this works well, my object changes color, and I know its position, but when I try to access the object's `userData` it displays `undefined`.

Is the object returned by the `intersectObject()` function not a copy of the original one ? I'm wondering if somewhere down the line it loses its properties.

```
    function onMouseMove(e) {

        var intersectedOne = false;

        for (var i = 0, len = group.children.length; i < len; i++) {
            setMaterial(group, material);
        }


        mouseVector.x = 2 * (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) - 1;
        mouseVector.y = 1 - 2 * (e.clientY / window.innerHeight);

        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouseVector, camera);

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(group.children, true);

        for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
            var intersection = intersects[i];
            var obj = intersection.object;
            if (intersection != 0 && intersectedOne == false) {
                intersectedOne = true;
                obj.material = selectedMaterial;
                text2.innerHTML = obj.userData.CADEIRA;
            }
        }
    }
```

`text2.innerHTML` shows `undefined` every time I hover over an object, while it should be showing the name of the object.

Comment: The objects you can obtain through `intersectObject` and `intersectObjects` are references --they're the same object-- so you must be doing something wrong, although it's not immediately obvious what. And `intersection != 0` makes no sense, though that should not cause the issue. Can you provide a jsfiddle please?

Comment: that's strange because I tried printing the userData of the array i'm passing to intersectObjects, just before I call that function, and all the metadata is there. I'll put up a jsFiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/electricganesha/ot7h6v49/3/ 

as you can see, when hovering the mouse on an object, the console print shows 'undefined', while just before, printing the array of objects passed to intersectObjects, contains the metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
var newObject = object.clone();
```

you should do

```
var newObject = child.clone();
```